# Rotating picture gallery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning JS with a little website project and stumbled upon the following problem:

- I have an image gallery with a couple of pictures
- I can always see 5 pics at a time
- one is big in the middle, left and right a second row and 2 more in the background

I already have two buttons to rotate through the gallery. now I want to make it possible to be able to rotate the gallery by clicking the pics on the left or right side of the middle picture.

The HTML gallery

```
<div class="gallery-container">
   <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-1" src="pictures/pic1.jpg" data-index="1">
   <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-2 prev-pic" src="pictures/pic2.jpg" data-index="2">
   <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-3" src="pictures/pic3.jpg" data-index="3">
   <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-4 next-pic" src="pictures/pic4.jpg" data-index="4">
   <img class="gallery-item gallery-item-5" src="pictures/pic5.jpg" data-index="5">
</div>
```

my Javascript

```
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
let galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');
let galleryArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(galleryItems); 

let prevPic = document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-2.prev-pic');
let listenerPrev = prevPic.addEventListener('click', function(prevEvent) {
  galleryArray.unshift(galleryArray.pop());
  updateGallery();
});

let nextPic = document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-4.next-pic');
let listnerNext = nextPic.addEventListener('click', function(nextEvent) {
  galleryArray.push(galleryArray.shift());
  updateGallery();
});

// Update css classes for gallery
function updateGallery() {
  galleryArray.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    el.classList.remove('prev-pic');
    el.classList.remove('next-pic');
  });

  galleryArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
  });

  document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-2').classList.add('prev-pic');
  document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-4').classList.add('next-pic');

  prevPic = document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-2.prev-pic');
  nextPic = document.querySelector('.gallery-item.gallery-item-4.next-pic');

}
```

My plan is to click the 'prevPic' and rotate the gallery. The first time clicking it works fine: the gallery rotates and the classes are updated. But when I click the new 'prevPic' it does nothing. What i noticed in my browser is that the 'event'-tag thats added in the html in the devoloper console doesnt move.

I hope someone understands my attempt to explain the matter and can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, the code looks good to me! Can you maybe share the HTML too? Preferably a small version of it with just the relevant parts, not all of it :)

Comment: There are no more relevant parts of my HTML than i already posted... there is just my container and the pictures in the gallery. the rest is done by js and css. I think i need something that makes it possible to refresh the Element the eventListerner refers to, but i dont know how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I would completely rethink my approach and do something like this, where I don't even store any of the elements as references; when a click happens I just look at what was clicked and react based on that. Would something like this work for your case?

```js
document.querySelector(".gallery-container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("prev")) {
    if (e.target.previousElementSibling) {
        e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("prev");
        e.target.classList.toggle("prev");
      e.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("next");
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("next");
    } else {
        alert("Cannot go more previous than this, friendo")
    }
    
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains("next")) {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling) {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("next");
        e.target.classList.toggle("next");
        e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("prev");
      e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("prev");
    } else {
        alert("Cannot go more next than this, friendo")
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.prev {border: 2px solid red;}
.next {border: 2px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
   <img class="gallery-item" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
   <img class="gallery-item prev" src="http://placekitten.com/49/49">
   <img class="gallery-item" src="http://placekitten.com/48/48">
   <img class="gallery-item next" src="http://placekitten.com/47/48">
   <img class="gallery-item" src="http://placekitten.com/46/46">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tried it out, but in the end found a slightly different way, that works better for me (but your approch gave me the idea):

I kept my function updateGallery() where I move the class name around my pics after the gallery got shifted

```
function updateGallery() {
  galleryArray.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
    el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    el.classList.remove('next');
    el.classList.remove('prev');
  });

  galleryArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
  });

  galleryArray[1].classList.add('prev');
  galleryArray[3].classList.add('next');
}
```

But access it this time but looping through the gallery:

```
for (var i=0; i<galleryArray.length; i++) {
  galleryArray[i].addEventListener ('click', function(e) {
    if (this.classList.contains('prev')) {
      galleryArray.unshift(galleryArray.pop());
      updateGallery();
    } else if (this.classList.contains('next')) {
      galleryArray.push(galleryArray.shift());
      updateGallery();
    }
  })
}
```